# AOP, how to intercept calls to a given class only when made directly from a package X

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I would like to intercept all calls made to a certain object: `org.springframework.data.redis.core.StringRedisTemplace` (e.g. `save();` `delete();`) but only when the calls are made directly from within one of my corporation many packages  `com.mycompany.*`, not when an instance of `StringRedisTemplace` is used by a third party library or spring/data/redis itself.

Is there a way to do that with AOP annotations like `@Pointcut` `@Around`, etc. My searches/attempts were unsuccessful.

So in one word => how to intercept/instrument all calls to all instances of a certain class as long as those instances were instantiated and used within my company packages.

Comment: I heard a bell, but you do not know (do not know) where it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are almost saying it by yourself:

> but only when the calls are made directly from **within** one of my corporation many packages `com.mycompany.*`

The pointcut type you need is indeed named `within`. There is a related one named `withincode` in full AspectJ, but proxy-based Spring AOP only supports the former, not the latter. For the latter you would have to use full AspectJ via LTW from within Spring. Everything is explained in the Spring manual's [AOP chapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop).

What you want to do is something like this:

```java
within(com.mycompany..*) && call(org.springframework.data.redis.core.StringRedisTemplate+.*(..))
```